# Middleware and Session Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have a problem with middleware and sessions in Laravel 8. I can't get the sessions previously registered in the middleware.

The next code is about my middleware, I tested with ->save(), Injection of Session/Store at construct, etc. Nothing work.

```
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(Store $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->session->has('test')) {
            dd('getting session', $this->session->get('test'));
        } else {
            $this->session->put('test', true);
            $this->session->save();
            dd('creating session...');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

And my middlewareGroup is the next, as you see, StartSession is before that my custom Middleware:

```
'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

            // Test middleware
            \App\Http\Middleware\TestingMid::class,
        ],
```

But I always get "creating session" message. What I'm missing?

Updated:

If I debug a little with `dd($this->session->isStarted())`, it show `true`.

Thanks

Comment: why would the session have a variable named `test` ... you keep setting a variable named `a` on the session

Comment: I notice that, sorry, bad copy/paste. I updated the post and same results.

Comment: you probably don't want to be calling `dd`, dump and die, you should let the request go through and let the startsession middleware do what it needs to save and close the session as the response comes back out of the middleware stack, you can use `dump` if you just want the data dumped without killing the script

Answer (score 2):

In the Kernel.
Your "EncryptCookies" must be after "StartSession".
In this way:

```
'web' => [

  \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
  \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
  // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
  \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

  // Test middleware
  \App\Http\Middleware\TestingMid::class,
],
```

Comment: This is not working nor explaining why he should move that line